# Notational Question : (a) = (b)

Tags: notation

What does the notation (a) = (b) mean? For context, a and b are elements of a ring. I have tried to find an answer by googling, but it's difficult to do this since I am not sure what to call it.

Comment: These two elements of the ring generate the same principle ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a ring $\,R\,$ the notation $(a)$ denotes $aR,\,$ the (principal) [ideal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_%28ring_theory%29) generated by $\,a.\,$ Thus $(a) = (b)$ means that $aR = bR,\,$ or, equivalently, $\,a\mid b\,$ and $\,b\mid a,\,$ i.e. $\,a\,$ and $\,b\,$ are associates. If, furthermore, $\,a\,$ and $\,b\,$ are cancellable, then this is equivalent to $\,a,b\,$ being  strong associates, i.e. $\,a = bu\,$ for some unit $\,u\,$ (but this [may fail](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/356007/242) without cancellability).

Answer (score 3):

In Algebra,Hungerford which is a standard book in ring theory, (a) is the principal ideal generated by a

Comment: This notation arises in other texts like Artin and Dummit & Foote as well.